# Wifi Direct Group Owner intent not functioning

Tags: android, wifi-direct

So I have an app that uses service discovery to connect multiple devices to one host. I start by setting everything up and then call WifiP2pManager.discoverServices(..). Then one device chooses to advertise the service (kind of like a game lobby). The other devices find it just fine and can connect no problem.

The problem arises when one device has already hosted the service and tries to connect to a device that was connected to its service (It formed a persistent group and ignores all group owner intent values).
Say we have a device A that hosts the service. Another device, B, connects to A, and A is the group owner and a persistent group is formed in the Wifi Direct Settings menu. Both finish using the app and decide to use it again at a later time. Now B decides to host the service. A tries to connect to B but ends up being group owner even though B is the one hosting the service because of the previous persistent connection.
At the later time I set device B's GOI (group owner intent) to 15 (host) and device A's GOI to 0 and it totally ignores it. EDIT [Actually I am only setting device A's GOI because only one device calls connect.]

My question is: Is there any way to remove old groups from the settings menu programmatically? Or do you have another suggestion on how to resolve my problem?

I  have tried using WifiP2pManager.createGroup(..) to create a new group and this fixes the group owner problem temporarily but after starting the service and connecting twice with the same device, it connects to the old, remembered group, and doesn't appear connected to the program. This could be easily fixed by not allowing persistent groups, but it appears that is not available as an option yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem. I am developing a simple server client application and the same problem occurred when i tried to switch the rolls. I resolved it by calling the [removeGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#removeGroup(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)) method in the server application every time the application closed. That way i made sure the group was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you set `groupOwnerIntent` to zero see below:

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
```

Then whenever you trying to connect device B from device A then device A becomes client and device B become server and viceversa only need is there should not be any group added in remembered group. This will not work from device settings so don't try. You need to create you own custom settings.

Answer (score 0):

use mP2pManager.removeGroup() at app close

P.S. I found no practical meaning for .groupOwnerIntent. You set it for device to be connected. From documentation it is totally unclear if it is property of commanding device or command to device to be connected